# CoreData performance duplicate entities vs properties

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm making an iOS app with thousands of flash cards with questions. The questions pool has about 10,000 questions, and is divided in 5 categories. One single question can have only one category. Categories won't change, they are fixed. Questions are just text. No images involved.

I was thinking about two approaches:

1) Create an Entity for the question with a category field (int) in it.

Fetch the results to get only the questions of a specific category.

2) Create 5 Entities, all with the same fields, except for the category, which has a default value corresponding with the category.

Why option 2?
I think option 1) is the clean proper one, but the app has so many questions that I'm thinking that submitting a query filtering a specific field, is maybe slower than retrieving a completely different Entity. I'm thinking from an SQL point of view, where  maybe performing a SELECT on one table and then another one, should be faster than a SELECT...WHERE on the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you, option 1 is the clean proper one.  Retrieving the category from another entity will add minimal overhead.  Moreover, if you have to edit a category you have only one entry to change.  You can also add other categories more easily.

If you are really concerned about performance (and I don't think you should at that point) you can code both and do a speed test.  But that is really overkill and the difference will probably be insignificant.